# How can I make enums accessible in another module in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

I have the following enum in a module (aka a .dart file):

```
enum HttpMethods { GET, POST, PUT, DELETE }
```

I would like to be able to import and use this enum inside a few classes in different modules. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `enum`s aren't any different than other identifiers in this regard.  You `import` the library that declares them and use them as you normally would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply import the file path inside another file and access it like that.

```
import '../enums/http_methods.dart';
final HttpMethods _myValue = HttpMethods.GET;
```

Or, create an `enums.dart` export file from which you export all your enums, and import this where you need it. It saves you from a lot of clutter down the line.

**enums.dart**

```
export 'http_methods.dart';
```

```
import '../enums.dart';
final HttpMethods _myValue = HttpMethods.GET;
```

Comment: Oh, my editor wasn't recognizing the import, but it compiles and runs just fine. Thank you!